# Delete unwanted content in column(not the whole column) in Pandas

Tags: pandas

What should I do if I only want to have `2016-06-29` shown in the timestamp column and delete the unwanted part like `15:46:43.895000`

[image]

Comment: Could you show any code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If timestamps:

```
 df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('d')
```

If strings:

```
 df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.split().str[0]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range('2016-06-29 15:46:43.895000', 
                               periods=3, 
                               freq='2000T')})
print (df)
                timestamp
0 2016-06-29 15:46:43.895
1 2016-07-01 01:06:43.895
2 2016-07-02 10:26:43.895

print (type(df.loc[0, 'timestamp']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>

df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('d')
print (df)
   timestamp
0 2016-06-29
1 2016-07-01
2 2016-07-02
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2016-06-20 15:46:43.895000', 
                                '2016-06-22 15:46:43.895000',
                                '2016-06-29 15:46:43.895000']})
print (df)
                    timestamp
0  2016-06-20 15:46:43.895000
1  2016-06-22 15:46:43.895000
2  2016-06-29 15:46:43.895000

print (type(df.loc[0, 'timestamp']))
<class 'str'>

df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.split().str[0]
print (df)
    timestamp
0  2016-06-20
1  2016-06-22
2  2016-06-29
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use `.dt.normalize()` method:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.normalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```